# Drawing Lines and Limiting Them by Screen Size in Python Turtle Graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need to add in proper handling of the initial length exceeding the screen size for my square spiral drawing program, however, I am unsure of what the length of the screen size is. I'm assuming since the Turtle graphics illustrator begins in the middle of the screen that it is halfway across the program window. In which case the code below should work I just need to know the length of the screen size.

```
while startLength >(screen size here):
    startLength=float(input("please enter a value greater than zero: "))
```

Also this needs to work universally on all platforms and assume one does not have a cross-platform like wx.

I have tried doing:

```
 while startLength >(turtle.forward(turtle.window_width()/2):
        startLength=float(input("please enter a value greater than zero: "))
```

However it exceeds the window size when I enter lengths between 300-350. Additionally when it finishes drawing the first line and turns 90 degrees to draw the next line of the spiral (downwards) it also exceeds the size of the screen.

I am using `import turtle`

Here is the full code from my program.

```
from turtle import *
import turtle
startLength = float(input("Please enter the length of first side: "))
while startLength < 0:
    startLength=float(input("please enter a value greater than zero: "))
while startLength > (turtle.window_width()/2):
    startLength=float(input("please enter a value that will fit in the window: "))
decrement = int(input("Please enter the change in length of side: "))
while startLength > decrement:
    forward(startLength)
    right(90)
    startLength = startLength - decrement   
forward(startLength)
right(90)
```

Comment: Just show the whole code you have, can't be that much. Note you can also put screenshots into your question.

Comment: Here is an image of the full code. http://imgur.com/IZctg2i

Comment: I know this might sound discouraging, but don't post code as images, just put in in like the code snippets above. That way people can just copy it and try to replicate your problem quickly.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I've added it to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally one would move the starting point away from the center to the top left, but here how to do it starting from the center. 
The only real difference to your code is only that I ask for the starting length, and then only keep asking (while loop) if it is too long. Ignore that I'm using `raw_input`, which is used for Python 2.x, same applies to print statements w/o parentheses.

```
import turtle  

bob = turtle.Turtle()
xx,yy= turtle.window_width(), turtle.window_height() 
print 'window size: ',xx,yy
bob.speed(15)

stl=int(raw_input("Please enter length of first side: "))   

while stl>turtle.window_width()/2:
    stl=int(raw_input("Please enter a shorter length that will fit into the window: "))

dec=int(raw_input("Please enter the change in length per iteration: "))   


while stl > dec:
    bob.forward(stl)
    bob.right(90)
    stl= stl- dec

turtle.done()
```

Text Output:

```
window size:  1280 1080
Please enter length of first side: 4000
Please enter a shorter length that will fit into the window: 3000
Please enter a shorter length that will fit into the window: 2000
Please enter a shorter length that will fit into the window: 1000
Please enter a shorter length that will fit into the window: 500
Please enter the change in length per iteration: 2
```

[image]

Additionally you could check for the height, if the window could ever be taller than wider.